# Replace a character within a shell script

Tags: bash, replace, str-replace

I have a script:

```
$cat ifile.sh
extension="name.f"
parameter_list="abc,xyz,stuv,ptq,rhu"
echo newfiles are $parameter_list
```

I would like to execute the ifile.sh and output should replace the comma `,` with extension i.e. `_name.f`. So my desire output will be

```
$sh ifile.sh
newfiles are abc_name.f xyz_name.f stuv_name.f ptq_name.f rhu_name.f
```

So I need to modify the `echo newfiles are $parameter_list`. I am trying with the follwoing

```
$cat ifile.sh
extension="name.f"
parameter_list="abc,xyz,stuv,ptq,rhu"
echo newfiles are sed -i 's/,/$extension/g' $parameter_list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a parameter expansion.

```
echo "newfiles are ${parameter_list//,/_$extension }_$extension"
```